# How do I find the time interval remaining from NSTimer

Tags: swift, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I have set a `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method which has an interval every 20 minutes. I want to be able to find out how much time is left when the the app goes into background mode. How do I find out how much time is left from the interval?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have access to a NSTimer's `fireDate`, which tells you when the timer is going to fire again.

The difference between now and the `fireDate` is an interval you can calculate using [NSDate's `timeIntervalSinceDate` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:).

E.G. something like:

```
let fireDate = yourTimer.fireDate
let nowDate = NSDate()
let remainingTimeInterval = nowDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(fireDate)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go!

Comment: Slightly shorter:  `yourTimer.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceNow`.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Solution of @Michael Dautermann with normal Swift type `Timer` and `Date` I have noticed, that his solution will give you a negative value e.g.:

```
let fireDate = yourTimer.fireDate
let nowDate = Date()
let remainingTimeInterval = nowDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(fireDate)
//above value is negative e.g. when the timers interval was 2 sec. and you 
//check it after 0.5 secs this was -1,5 sec.
```

When you insert a negative value in the `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:,target:,selector:,userInfo:,repeats:)` function it would lead to a timer set to 0.1 milliseconds as the [Documentation of the `Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) mentions it.

So in my case I had to use the negative value of the `nowDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(fireDate)` result: `-nowDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(fireDate)`